# How to use jsp jstl set attribute in javascript code

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, jstl

im using boostarp tab in a jsp page.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="courseSearchTabs">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a id="stark" data-toggle="tab" href="#filter">${messages.all_courses}</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a id="he" data-toggle="tab" href="#isbn">${messages.custom_courses}</a>
                </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="filter" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>HOME</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="isbn" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

when the boostrap tab is onchange we set a attribute on request scope as follow

```
 <script>

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var tab = $(e.target);
        var contentId = tab.attr("id");

        if(contentId == 'stark') {
            <c:set var="coursestype" value="stark" scope="request"/>

        }else if(contentId == 'he') {
            <c:set var="coursestype" value="he" scope="request"/>

        }

    });

</script>
```

then im trying to output jstl set value as follow.but im getting the same value and value is not changing when i swip the boostrap tabs.

```
 <c:out value="${requestScope.coursestype}"/>
```

Comment: Not related but this thing `<li role="presentation">` makes no sense here, instead use `role` in `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**,you can not do it like this.

> You can get javascript value from JSTL,but you can not get jstl value
>   set by javascript

`javascript` is a client side language,and `JSTL` is a server side language,in `HTTP` first we need send the request then we can receive response from the server
So we can not set value in server language without a request.

When you check the html source of your page,you will find that `jstl` value has been already calculated and `<c:out value="${requestScope.coursestype}"/>` will become empty in your case

Comment: is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: you need to change your design,such as get value by JavaScript instead of JSTL